# Honeymoon destination options

Tags: international-travel, destinations

I am wondering about honeymoon destinations around the globe in December. Something with mountains and water (beach or waterfall). Particularly, a place where we can stay right next to a big waterfall closest to a mountain. Possibly too dreamy!! Anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE, but I'm afraid this is way too broad in its current form, you'll need to narrow down your criteria a lot more.

Comment: Or wander into your nearest suitable Bricks & Mortar travel agent, and ask them. They'll have brochures you can look through, can give you advice, can help you book it etc.

Comment: Make this a wiki style one so its no longer question answer any more and you can share the knowledge with others